# Why won't my code work inside another code?

Tags: python

I have a script that calculates BLEU score and another script that does the same but based on the POS tags of the words. When I combine them into one code together the POS tag files are created are empty and the code crashes giving me this error:

`sentences=cube(sentences)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`

Since the files are empty, I am not quite sure why.

I've tried making the POS- file creation into a function. Still doesn't work.

```
from nltk.translate.bleu_score import sentence_bleu
from nltk.translate.bleu_score import SmoothingFunction
import argparse
import sys
import csv
from cube.api import Cube

cube=Cube(verbose=True)
cube.load("en")

def argparser():
    Argparser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    Argparser.add_argument('--reference', type=str, default='summaries.txt', help='Reference File')
    Argparser.add_argument('--candidate', type=str, default='candidates.txt', help='Candidate file')

    args = Argparser.parse_args()
    return args

args = argparser()

reference = open(args.reference, 'r').readlines()
candidate = open(args.candidate, 'r').readlines()


with open('pos_r.txt', 'w') as out1, open('pos_h.txt', 'w')as out2:
    for sentences in reference:
        sentences=cube(sentences)
        for sentence in sentences:
            for entry in sentence:
                    out1.write(entry.upos+"\t"+entry.attrs)
                out1.write('')
    for sentences in candidate:
        sentences=cube(sentences)
        for sentence in sentences:
            for entry in sentence:
                out2.write(entry.upos+"\t"+entry.attrs)
                out2.write('')


with open('results.txt','w')as out:
### BLEU
    cc=SmoothingFunction()

    if len(reference) != len(candidate):
     raise ValueError('The number of sentences in both files do not match.')

    score = 0.

    for i in range(len(reference)):
     score += sentence_bleu([reference[i].strip().split()], candidate[i].strip().split(),smoothing_function=cc.method5)

    score /= len(reference)
    out.write('BLEU score is ' +  '{:.3}'.format(score))

### POSBLEU
    with open('pos_r.txt', 'r') as f1, open('pos_h.txt', 'r')as f2:
        f1=f1.readlines()
        f2=f2.readlines()
        if len(f1) != len(f2):
            raise ValueError('The number of sentences in both files do not match.')

        score = 0.

        for i in range(len(f1)):
            score += sentence_bleu([f1[i].strip().split()], f2[i].strip().split(),smoothing_function=cc.method5)

        score /= len(f1)
        out.write('POSBLEU score is ' +  '{:.3}'.format(score))
```

Comment: Is `Cube` a class you wrote?  If you are going to call it like `cube(sentences)` it will need a `__call__` member function.

Comment: No, its NLP cube (https://github.com/adobe/NLP-Cube) that needs to be initialised this way

Comment: Wow, this is baffling.  This is saying that **cube == None**.  But that seems clearly to not be the case.  I must be missing something in my understanding here.   You're sure this is exactly the code you're running to get that error?

Comment: The error is not there when the pos files are not empty and the code works on its own, so that is why. I do not really get why it stops working if combined with another code. :/ (I've tried them separately and they work fine)

Comment: You're sure about which line that error is coming from? - could it actually be coming from inside the call to **cube()**?  Do you have a full error message and stack trace that you can put in your question?

Comment: I thought of that, but if that was the case why doesn't it complain when I split the two of them and run them separately? It tries to process sentences, but since the files are empty it cannot.

Comment: Well, that's a different question depending on where the error is coming from.  As long as you are getting an error, I would concentrate on that first.  But maybe you're saying that you understand the error you're getting, and that the problem is really just that **sentences** is None or otherwise not what is expected?

Comment: Yes, I do understand where the error comes from. What I don't understand is mainly my title. Why do these two codes work separately, but when combined they crash? Why aren't the pos_r.txt and pos_h.txt created? It truly baffles me.

Comment: Most of your code isn't in play here, since this problem occurs early in your code.  It seems that you are simply reading all the lines in a file and passing those lines to **cube()**.  You do this with two different files.  So the problem must be either with your input, or with the logic in **cube()**, if that's where the error is coming from.  I'd say follow the execution in a debugger.  I don't see that there's enough information in your question for anyone to be able to tell you what is wrong. - I'd suggest at least posting the full error message, including the stack trace.

Comment: Maybe someone who knows Cube well would be able to guess what's wrong here.  I don't know that package, so I have no idea what **cube()** might be having a problem with.

Comment: Can you paste the full text of the error?